# Adding an object to a vector in the middle of an iteration error

Tags: c++, loops, vector, containers, sfml

Alright so, I'm in the middle of a loop that iterates all objects in a vector:

```
for (auto &itr : m_entities) {
    itr.second->Update(l_time);
    if (itr.second->m_isDead) 
        Remove(itr.first); //don't worry, it does not remove immediately so the vector size wont change 
    }
```

`m_entities` is a vector that processes derived objects inherited from a base class, and the loop simply calls the `Update()` function of each object in that vector. Simple enough, and everything was working fine.

However, when I decided to call the `Add()` function, which simply adds a new object to the vector, I get an exception:

> _Myval2 was 0xDDDDDDDD

I know the problem: I am calling the `Add()` function inside of the `Update()` function in one of the derived classes, which changes the size of the vector while still doing the iteration. Like so:

```
for (auto &itr : m_entities) {
    itr.second->Update(l_time); //here is where I call "Add," changing the size of the vector  
    if (itr.second->m_isDead)   //and messing everything up
        Remove(itr.first);
}
```

So my question is: How can I add to the vector *INSIDE* of the loop and still be able to finish the loop without getting an error?

PS: I need to add it inside of the loop. The feature that I want doesn't work if I do like I did with the `Remove()` function. The `Remove()` function only pushes the ID of the entity to a vector that will be later deleted from the vector. Yes, it will work if I do something like that with the `Add()` function, but as soon as I add the entity inside the loop, I want to modify it:

```
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) {
    if (...) {
        ...

        //Here it will add to the vector and return the entity ID, which 
        //I use to find the entity and modify it right away
        unsigned int bulletId = m_entityMgr->Add(EntityType::Bullet);

        //just a pointer to the newly added entity so I can modify it
        Bullet *bullet = (Bullet*)m_entityMgr->Find(bulletId);

        ... //modifying entity
    }
}
```

And then right after it exits from this `Update()` function, it goes back to that loop and the error pops up because the size of the vector was modified.

Comment: You can't do anything that changes the number of elements in a container while using range-based `for`. You [invalidate the iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) it's using as book-keeping. Some containers are more forgiving than others, but this is one case where `vector` is less-than-friendly.

Comment: Is there a solution for this without invalidating it?

Comment: Can't you just store those pointers resulting from `Add/Find` and process them afterwards (like you do with `Remove`)?

Comment: Tactical note on the remove code: [Look up `std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). You should be able to get it to work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a range-based `for` loop, you can't do anything that modifies the size of the container.  In this case, since you are only adding elements, simply use a traditional index-based `for` loop instead, eg:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < m_entities.size(); ++i)
{
    auto &itr = m_entities[i];
    itr.second->Update(l_time); // may increase the size of the vector
    if (itr.second->m_isDead)
        Remove(itr.first);
}
```

Or, if you don't want to call `Update()` on new items added:

```cpp
size_t size = m_entities.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    auto &itr = m_entities[i];
    itr.second->Update(l_time); // may increase the size of the vector
    if (itr.second->m_isDead)
        Remove(itr.first);
}
```